# Outer Join with Multiple Inner Join In a Single Query

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to use Outer Join with inner Join in a single query

Query:

```
select d.unit_name, a.tour_code, a.hub_code, b.name, c.pp_no, c.dte_of_expiry
from bkng_mst a , bkng_pax b, bkng_cust c, unit_mst d
where a.bkng_id = b.bkng_id 
and b.unit_cde = d.unit_cde 
and a.unit_cde = d.unit_cde 
and b.cust_id = c.cust_id 
and a.bkng_stat = 'CNF' 
and b.bkng_pax_cancel_flg = 'N' 
and a.bkng_id = 'XXXX'
```

**Use Outer Join from Table pax_dtl pd on a.bkng_id=pd.bkng_id along with above query**

Comment: OK....what have you tried ?

Comment: The above Query works properly but want to use Outer Join along with this query. Need help as i m clueless

Answer (score 0):

## UPDATED :

I think that, taking into account the information provided in your comments, the following query should be helpful:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    d.unit_name, a.tour_code, a.hub_code, b.name, c.pp_no, c.dte_of_expiry,
    pd.bkng_id, pd.unit_name, pd.tour_code, pd.pax_name, pd.pnr_no, pd.fare_base, pd.is_block, pd.is_system
FROM 
    bkng_mst a 
    INNER JOIN bkng_pax b
       ON a.bkng_id = b.bkng_id
    INNER JOIN bkng_cust c 
       ON b.cust_id = c.cust_id
    INNER  JOIN unit_mst d
       ON b.unit_cde = d.unit_cde 
          AND a.unit_cde = d.unit_cde
    LEFT OUTER JOIN pax_dtl pd 
        ON a.bkng_id=pd.bkng_id 
WHERE  
    a.bkng_stat = 'CNF' 
    AND b.bkng_pax_cancel_flg = 'N' 
    AND a.bkng_id = 'XXXX'
```

Because of **1 to many** relation between `bkng_mst` and `pax_dtl` tables, the columns `d.unit_name, a.tour_code, a.hub_code, b.name, c.pp_no, c.dte_of_expiry` from above query will repeat only if for 1 particular `bkng_id` value there will be at least one different value among the columns `pd.bkng_id, pd.unit_name, pd.tour_code, pd.pax_name, pd.pnr_no, pd.fare_base, pd.is_block`.

I hope it might help you, but in case of any doubts please write.

Comment: I'm sorry - I had a little mistake in query - updated minute ago and should be Ok. Please try if you might.

Comment: Its returning duplicate records. It should return 3 records but it returns 9 records. 3X3

Comment: Please tell, whether between table `bkng_mst` and table `pax_dtl` is **1 to 1** relation or **1 to many** - basing on field `bkng_id`? If you might you may try the above query without `LEFT Outer Join pax_dtl pd on a.bkng_id=pd.bkng_id` to ensure whether it is restructuring problem.

Comment: Its a 1 to many relation. 1 bkng_id in bkng_mst table has multiple records in pax_dtl table. I tried without Left Outer Join its working fine. But I have to use Left Join.

Comment: Could you list all the columns from `pax_dtl` that you need to be placed in the result set?

Comment: bkng_id, unit_name, tour_code, pax_name, pnr_no,fare_base,is_block,is_system are the columns in pax_dtl where i have to join on bkng_id
Table bkng_pax b returns 3 rows for that bkng_id and that the reason for duplication